# Maven concat/merge META-INF/service/file of two dependencies using maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, meta-inf

G'day!

I have two dependencies in my project that are overwriting each others `config-files` within `META-INF/services/xxx`.

Is there some procedure to *merge/concat*  these two configs files instead of overwriting?

Any ideas are well appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should take a look at the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) it might be better.